# Override self-insert-command or input-decode-map

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was looking for an example of overriding a bunch of key bindings, so that I could, press <kbd>S-z h</kbd> and the actual result printed would be "Ж" (this is Cyrillic capital letter Zhe), but any other sequence starting with <kbd>S-z</kbd> would insert "З" (Cyrillic capital Ze) and the next character typed as if it was starting a new sequence, in a dedicated mode of course.

So far I found this: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Translation-Keymaps.html (the very bottom of the page), but I can't get it to do anything / don't really understand what this example is trying to show :(

If you will take the time to write a simple example of overriding the self-insert-command or any other way to get the above done, I would really appreciate that!

EDIT:
*(here's what I was trying so far)*

```
(defun transliterate ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (upcase last-input-char)))

(define-key (current-global-map)
  [remap self-insert-command]
  'transliterate)
```

EDIT2:
http://pastebin.com/uBFmspmf I could get the desired effect, but the code is very ugly :( So, suggestions are still welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer:  I don't use multi-language features in Emacs, so this may not be the best approach, and I may even have reinvented the wheel here, but:

```
(defvar zhe-mode-mapping
  '((?h . ?Ж)))

(defvar zhe-mode-prefix-key [(meta i)])

(defun zhe-mode-insert (n)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((mapping (assq last-input-event zhe-mode-mapping)))
    (if mapping
        (apply 'insert (make-list n (string (cdr mapping))))
      (if (eq (lookup-key (current-global-map) (single-key-description last-input-event))
              'self-insert-command)
          (progn
            (insert "З")
            (self-insert-command n))
        (error "%s does not self-insert" (single-key-description last-input-event) )))))

(defvar zhe-mode-override-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (map-keymap (lambda (key def)
                  (when (eq def 'self-insert-command)
                    (nconc map (list (cons key 'zhe-mode-insert)))))
                (current-global-map))
    (keymap-canonicalize map)))

(define-minor-mode zhe-mode
  "blah blah"
  nil
  "zhe"
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map zhe-mode-prefix-key zhe-mode-override-map)
    map))
```

Active the minor-mode with `zhe-mode` command.  Customize `zhe-mode-key` to `[(super z)]` to do what you wanted.  I don't have super mapped on my keyboard.  Enjoy.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I don't use multi-language features.  I was just going by what I could parse from your description of the problem.  I see your code from pastebin does something quite different from the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the definition of other keyboards, for example the Czech keyboard uses <kbd>=</kbd> to insert accent over some characters (e.g. *á*), but when followed by a character that cannot be accented, it print both of them (e.g. =f). For example, see here:

http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/astaff/source/src-8.4/third/emacs/leim/quail/czech.el